# I am using a select in form field. data is inserted properly but displayed id only instead of text

Tags: laravel, select

Create page

```php
<div class="form-group">
        <label><b>STATUS</b></label>
        {!! Form::select('status', ['Draft','Published']) !!}
</div>
```

Index page

```php
@foreach($sliders as $slider)
      <tr>
          <td>{!! $slider->id !!}</a></td>

           <td>{!! $slider->status !!}</td>    

@endforeach
```

Controller

```php
public function store(Slider $slider,CreateSliderRequest $request)
{
 // $slider=$slider->lists('name','id');
    $slider = $slider->create($request->all());       
    Session::flash('message', 'The photo was successfully added!.');
    Session::flash('flash_type', 'alert-success');
    return redirect('sliders');

}
```

At index page, the data is shown in text dropdown, after inserting it navigate to index page, and in index page it shows status as 0 instead of showing Draft or Published.

Data are stored as id and id are displayed, i want to display text instead of id..
anyone there for help?

Comment: Maybe not related question, but you didn't closed the `</tr>` in your `@foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide how to structure your status options. If your array is not an assoc array, the option values will be the indices `0,1,...` as in:

```
<select name="status">
    <option value="0">Draft</option>
    <option value="1">Published</option>
</select>
```

In your case, I assume you want to store `'Draft' or 'Published`, so you should do this:

```
{!! Form::select('status', ['Draft' => 'Draft', 'Published' => 'Published']) !!}
```

so that the HTML generated would be

```
<select name="status">
    <option value="Draft">Draft</option>
    <option value="Published">Published</option>
</select>
```